# Why?! cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory

Tags: bash, directory, parent, cp

I have one command(which works, but everything is copy-paste from the terminal output when script is running):

```
cp --parents mcare.properties /mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Release/CRMT-mcare/msite-binaries-UAT/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
```

And this command is executed by a script with variables instead of files name or directories and it is looking like this(and this one is not working):

```
cp --parents $source $destination
```

Logs to see what is in every variable:

```
source=mcare.properties
pwd:
/mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Workspaces-CVS/Release-CRMT-mcare/mCare/config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  6724 Feb 29 19:50 activareCont.properties
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     0 Feb 29 20:10 CVS
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  2333 Aug 25 17:55 externalpartner.properties
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  1764 May 26 10:36 login.properties
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10068 Aug 25 17:55 mcare.properties
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  8551 May 27 16:04 msite.properties
config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
medium=UAT
/mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Release/CRMT-mcare/msite-binaries-UAT/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

The code snippet itself:

```
        cd $SOURCE/"${line%mcare*}"
        source="mcare.properties"
        echo source=$source
        echo "pwd:"
        pwd
        ls -l
        echo $line
        medium="${line#*config/}"
        echo $medium
        medium="${medium%/home*}"
        echo medium=${medium}""
        destination=$DEST/msite-binaries-$medium/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
        echo $destination
        cp --parents $source $destination
```

I posted a piece of my own code because I occur this issue only in this conditions. I am not sure how I can explain it otherwise.

Reply to Charles Duffy after executed bash -x scriptname. Same line executed at that location (pwd), it is working if I execute it in terminal, separatly:

```
+ cd /mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Workspaces-CVS/Release-CRMT-mcare/mCare/config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/
+ source=mcare.properties
+ echo source=mcare.properties
source=mcare.properties
+ echo pwd:
pwd:
+ pwd
/mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Workspaces-CVS/Release-CRMT-mcare/mCare/config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
+ ls -l
total 16
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  6724 Feb 29 19:50 activareCont.properties
drwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     0 Feb 29 20:10 CVS
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  2333 Aug 25 17:55 externalpartner.properties
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  1764 May 26 10:36 login.properties
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 10068 Aug 25 17:55 mcare.properties
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 root root  8551 May 27 16:04 msite.properties
+ echo config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
+ medium=UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
+ echo UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
+ medium=UAT
+ echo medium=UAT
medium=UAT
+ destination=/mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Release/CRMT-mcare/msite-binaries-UAT/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
+ echo /mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Release/CRMT-mcare/msite-binaries-UAT/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
/mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Release/CRMT-mcare/msite-binaries-UAT/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
+ cp --parents mcare.properties /mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Release/CRMT-mcare/msite-binaries-UAT/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

Code snippet which I ran in http://www.shellcheck.net/:

```
cd /mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Workspaces-CVS/Release-CRMT-mcare/mCare/config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/ || exit
        source="mcare.properties"
        line=config/UAT/home/wlp/mcare/WEB-INF/classes/mcare.properties
        echo source=$source
        DEST=/mnt/hgfs/Shared-workspace/Release/CRMT-mcare
        echo "pwd:"
        pwd
        ls -l
        echo $line
        medium="${line#*config/}"
        echo $medium
        medium="${medium%/home*}"
        echo medium=${medium}""
        destination=$DEST/msite-binaries-$medium/mcare/WEB-INF/classes
        echo $destination
        declare -p destination
        cp  --parents $source $destination
```

Comment: please post text files as text not images it's horrible to read impossible to copy/paste.

Comment: Not only that, but if we allowed questions which couldn't be understood without following a link, our Q&A knowledge base would fall apart due to linkrot. We're trying to build this to last; thus, it's mandatory that questions be self-contained.

Comment: ...to quote the relevant close reason: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**".

Comment: ...when editing/updating the question to conform with these rules, do also note that the code given should actually be *sufficient* to reproduce the problem. If you need a file to exist, use `touch` to create the file. If you need a directory to exist, use `mkdir` to create the directory -- in short, your code should create the problem if Joe Random User copies-and-pastes it to run on some random out-of-the-box install. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for further guidance here.

Comment: Ok, I added the code snippet I used to check in shellcheck.net

Comment: Interesting -- apparently http://shellcheck.net/ suppresses [SC2086](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2086) when variables are assigned with constant values that can't trigger the relevant bugs.

Comment: Something is still missing I think. The same code (I'm 100% sure it was not modified), was ok few weeks ago. Just some input and script call has been modified. If the $destionation will be: destination=$DEST/msite-binaries-$medium/mcare , the same code will run just fine now. Also another script which is 95% similar to this, run ok in the same conditions. It is just using a directory hierarchy in source and destionation, something like: cp --parrent /otherdirectory/insideone/insidetwo/file.properties /destionation/otherotherdir/

Comment: Found out the real problem. --parents it is required to keep the same directory structure when cp(it fits better for current needs). For example, 99% files are copied something like: cp --parents /d/e/f.properties /a/b/c. But the error came from fact directory /a/b/c is not created yet. In the end, file should be at location like /a/b/c/d/e/f.properties. I tough --parents is able to create directory to that structure, but it is only cp the structure from source... . Now when I'm thinking everything looks so silly and obvious... Thanks for any constructive/helpful answer received

Answer (score 5):

`cp --parents` is a non-POSIX extension responsible for running an operation equivalent to `mkdir -p`, and provides no benefit you couldn't get via `mkdir -p` itself. Thus, the simple answer is to stop using it:

```
mkdir -p -- "$destination" || exit
cp -- "$source" "$destination/"
```

---

If using GNU `cp`, the codepath printing the error message at hand is only accessible when the `target_directory` variable is empty. One way to ensure that this is always set is using the GNU extension `-t`:

```
[[ -d "$destination" ]] || {
  echo "$destination is not a reachable directory" >&2
  exit 1
}
cp -t "$destination" -- "$source" || exit
```